# How to program pitch depending colored line sections with matplotlib

Tags: numpy, matplotlib

I'm printing a chart with a line coming from 2 numpy arrays with same number of floats in them like this and it's working fine.

```
f_used = sp.interpolate.interp1d(time, distance, kind='cubic')
timeinterp = sp.arange(0, runtime+incr, incr)
distinterp = f_used(timeinterp)
plt.plot(timeinterp, distinterp, '-', lw=3, c="red" )
```

So far, so good. In a next step I want to draw line sections depending on their pitch (`distinterp / timeinterp`). If the ratio is > 5.0 then let us say the line-style should be "dotted" or/and gets another color.
I cannot find any solution. Has somebody an idea?

If it helps: Raspbian on Raspberry Pi 3, all software updated, using Python3

Comment: Please take a look at how I edited your question and format your code blocks the same way (4 spaces indent) in the future. Makes it easier on the eyes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will effectively have to separate the data into the different portions that you want since each line object can only have one style/color/etc. combination assigned to it.

This should be trivial using numpy (or scipy, which in your case is just importing the underlying numpy functions directly):

```
mask = (distinterp / timeinterp) > 5.0
plt.plot(timeinterp[mask], distinterp[mask], ':', lw=3, c='r')
plt.plot(timeinterp[~mask], distinterp[~mask], '-', lw=3, c='b')
```

A better way might be to use matplotlib's object oriented API:

```
mask = (distinterp / timeinterp) > 5.0
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(timeinterp[mask], distinterp[mask], ':', lw=3, c='r')
ax.plot(timeinterp[~mask], distinterp[~mask], '-', lw=3, c='b')
```

Comment: Good answer, but would you mind deleting the statement about [`plt.hold(True)`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hold) which does not make any sense. Subsequent calls of `plot` will always plot to the same axes and the use of `plt.hold` is depreciated.

Comment: Many thanks for this fast answer. Seems to work. Now I can work further on.